# c++ if statement with extra condition

Tags: c++, if-statement

I would like to know how to add an extra name to this `if` statement. I tried a lot of things, but they didn't seem to work. This is my code at the moment:

```
string name = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(this->Playerptr + 32);//

if (this->beginWith("/maxstatsz") && this->GetAdmin() >= 8 && !name.compare("jack")) {// 
    this->forward = false; // 
    this->Buff(46, (30 * 60), 1000);// 
    this->Buff(47, (30 * 60), 1000);//
    this->Buff(48, (30 * 60), 1000);
    this->Buff(49, (30 * 60), 1000);
    this->Buff(12, (30 * 60), 1000);
    Server::CPlayer::Write((void*)this->Playerptr, 60, "ss", "Server", "#Enabled Buffs!");//
}
```

This command will now work only for a player with `adminrights >= 8` with the name `jack`. I tested it and it works fine.

But now I want to add also another player name to it that would be able to use this command too.

I added this under `Server::CPlayer` with the `Buff`s under it, of course, but this didn't work:

```
else if (this->beginWith("/maxstatsz") && this->GetAdmin() >= 8 && !name.compare("hero")) {//
```

etc.

This didnt work too

```
if (this->beginWith("/maxstatsz") && this->GetAdmin() >= 8 && !name.compare("jack") || this->beginWith("/maxstatsz") && this->GetAdmin() >= 8 && !name.compare("john")) {
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe I need to use `OR` instead of an `else if` statement?

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I personally, would make a list of "special names", and scan that inside the first if-statement. When mixing and / or, you probably want some extra parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked fine.

Comment: Added a quick (and incomplete) list of "code smells" to my answer. Seriously, go to codereview and get some feedback on your code style. The way you're using the language is error-prone, hard to maintain, and *will* get raised eyebrows from anyone who'll ever have to work with your code. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ( this->beginWith("/maxstatsz") &&
     ( this->GetAdmin() >= 8 ) &&
     ( !name.compare("jack") || !name.compare("hero") )
   )
```

What Mats commented, basically. Liberally add parenthesis when using multiple subconditions.

Also, your code has *many*, let's say, stylistic defects. I won't go into them, but will recommend going to [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get some feedback on how to write better C++.

Just a quick list of what caught my eye:

- `this->` is unnecessary.
- `reinterpret_cast<>`, unless you are *forced* to use it by external influences, is always a code smell.
- You should not be using "magic numbers" (32, 46, ...) in your source; declare named constants instead.
- Even better, you shouldn't "poke around" in `this->Buff`, but instead call member functions (`resetBuffer()`, or `blankPlayground()`, or `addGold( 1000 )` or whatever).
- If `name` is `std::string`, you can compare `( name == "jack" || name == "hero" )`, which is much clearer.
- What Remy wrote about a list of allowed names (and +1 to him).

Comment: @Melebius: I won't even go there. There is no way to get this "right" in everyone's eye. And anyway, your editor / IDE should auto-reindent the source to your project's style anyway. ;-)

Comment: As a loose preference, it's often hard to reason about a long list of mixed positive and negative conditions. `(name == "jack" || name == "hero")` is more readable.

Comment: @Useless: OP's usage of `name.compare()` (which, judging from the `!`, returns 0 on equal) made me doubt that `string name` is actually `std::string`, but rather something else. That's one of the stylistic defects I was talking about. Of course, having `operator==` available would make the statement that much clearer.

Comment: `std::string` does have a `compare` method that behaves this way - there's just no reason to use it if you only want to test equality.

Comment: @Useless: That's what made me doubt that what OP called "string" is actually something that *has* `operator==`. I didn't want to start making too many guesses on his code, hoping to see him on codereview.SE to get this mess sorted out properly. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (this->beginWith("/maxstatsz") &&
    (this->GetAdmin() >= 8) &&
    ((name =="jack") || (name == "hero"))) {//
    ...
}
```

Or, something more like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
names.push_back("jack");
names.push_back("hero"); 
... 

if (this->beginWith("/maxstatsz") &&
    (this->GetAdmin() >= 8) &&
    (std::find(names.begin(), names.end(), name) != names.end())) {//
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.